# useEffect not working to update localStorage data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, drag-and-drop, draggable, react-tsx

I'm trying to save a list of completed to-dos when dragging it to the completed to-dos list, using the following code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("completedTodies", JSON.stringify(completedTodies));
  }, [completedTodies]);
```

But this useEffect only renders once, and doesn't update my localStorage data.

Thats the code that keeps listening the changes when i drag-n-drop the todos:

```
const onDragEnd = (result: DropResult) => {
    const { source, destination } = result;

    if (!destination) return;
    if (
      destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
      destination.index === source.index
    )
      return;

    let add,
      active = todies,
      completed = completedTodies;

    if (source.droppableId === "activeTodies") {
      add = active[source.index];
      active.splice(source.index, 1);
    } else {
      add = completed[source.index];
      completed.splice(source.index, 1);
    }

    if (destination.droppableId === "activeTodies") {
      add.isDone = false;
      active.splice(destination.index, 0, add);
    } else {
      add.isDone = true;
      completed.splice(destination.index, 0, add);
    }

    setCompletedTodies(completed);
    setTodies(active);
  };
```

I've tried putting console.logs to see if the function was being triggered, but nothing seems to work. The only way that works, is when i drag a todo to the completed list and then type something like a console.log(e.g) and then save the file.

Comment: Arrays are passed by reference which means that when you use `completed = completedTodies`, you're giving completedTodies another name to reference the same array.  So, you need to create a copy instead.  You can do that with `completed = [...completedTodies]`.

Comment: But the `useEffect` should be triggered when i use the `setCompletedTodies(completed);`